# Android Device Movement pattern

Tags: android

I want to get the device movement and recognize the shape, like when  i move my physical device in square pattern the app will draw a square and so on, can anyone help me.I have tried acceleratormeter but it did helped.

Comment: Any code of what you have tried already?

Comment: I was studying this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-accel but i dont know how will i get the movement shape ? i want to know is there any other thing i can use